# Convert dwg file with external refernced .tif file to Svg

Tags: autocad

I have few .dwg file which have linked external .tif file. And I want to convert that to .svg file so that we can display the image on browser.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your question right. Please be precise.
What you could do is copy the References to a certain layer in Autocad, so it is in the dwg itself and then use one of the "DWG to SVG Converter" which you can find on google.
This online converter for example: [DWG to SVG Converter](https://cloudconvert.com/dwg-to-svg)!

Hope I could help you.

Comment: Hi Martin,
Thanks for your response , I have tried almost all the software which convert dwg file to svg ,but none of them was able to pick up external referenced .tif (image file)and save that in .svg file with layer information.

Dwg to svg converter you referenced was closest to just ing tif file name after conversion.

Comment: Hi guneet, I understand. But if you export or convert a file normally it doesn't save refernces too. That's because the reference i not part of the actual file.
If possible try to copy and past the reference in the actual file, maybe on a additional layer or default it doesn't matter as log the data is in the dwg file itself.
You could also just "import" the file like this
(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=skkbHWBjk8U)
(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hdq4mMJKE-Y)

Comment: Hi Martin,
I think our team tried to import the files , but as tif file are too big and also we have around 30k files , this process will take lot of time and effort . Therefore this is not an option for us. Thanks for your suggestion though.

Comment: Welcome! If you find the solution you could post it, that everyone can get a help.